# Bricked Tp-Link WR802N Access Point

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I installed OpenWRT to my Access Point but then I wanted to switch to the old firmware. I flashed the old firmware and now my AP is bricked. I connected it to my PC over ethernet but connection goes up for about a second and goes down very quickly. Light turn on for about a second and turn off again in sync with the connection. I looked at the Package dump and there's nothing but ARP requests by my PC when I use static IP address, when I use DHCP there's only DHCP request. I tried changing power adapters, cables and waiting for a while but nothing helped. I tried TFTP firmware update but it doesn't work either.

Comment: What revision number is on the underside sticker?

Comment: It says it's v1

Comment: Are you trying to get OpenWRT back on it? Or are you trying to get the original tp-link firmware back on it?

Comment: Either of them will do, I just need it to make it work again.